# IP address pattern match and replace in YML configuration file

Tags: unix, awk, sed

I want to replace IP address for config file abc.conf  with $IP 
IP=xx.xx.xx.xx

```
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1
```

sample output

```
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: xx.xx.xx.xx
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -E 's/(bindIp: )(.*)/\1xx.xx.xx.xx/g' abc.conf
```

Edited with some explanation:

- Find a line with the word `bindIP:` + some content.

  - `()` group content that can be called with `\1`, `\2`, etc.
  - `(bindIp: )` - Find the word `bindIP:` and point to group `\1`
  - In regex, `.*` matches with a content of any length (0 to infinite).
  - `(.*)` - Find a content of any lenght and point to group `\2`.
- Replace the content found with `\1xx.xx.xx.xx`

  - `\1` - the content of the first group (`bindIP:` itself)
  - `xx.xx.xx.xx` - a string

The `-E` parameter is to be not necessary to escape parenthesis inside the expression.

Comment: Can you provide some explanation for why this solution works?